# Entering date of the day of the week in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a time card worksheet for my employees to submit.  Column A is the day name and I want column B to auto-populate the date of that day. Here is the module I have created...

```
Sub AutoDate()

    Dim NextSun As Date
    Dim NextMon As Date
    Dim NextTues As Date
    Dim NextWed As Date
    Dim NextThur As Date
    Dim NextFri As Date
    Dim NextSat As Date


    '*****Autopopulate the dates of the day of the week*****

    NextSun = ((Weekday(Date, vbSunday)))
    Range("C26") = NextSun
    NextSun = ((Weekday(Date, vbMonday)))
    Range("C27") = NextMon
    NextSun = ((Weekday(Date, vbTuesday)))
    Range("C28") = NextTues
    NextSun = ((Weekday(Date, vbWednesday)))
    Range("C29") = NextWed
    NextSun = ((Weekday(Date, vbThursday)))
    Range("C30") = NextThur
    NextSun = ((Weekday(Date, vbFriday)))
    Range("C31") = NextFri
    NextSat = ((Weekday(Date, vbSaturday)))
    Range("C32") = NextSat

End Sub
```

Thank you in advance for your assistance in this matter.

Comment: How do you get a date from only a day name?

Comment: There's no question in your question, so I'm not sure what you want help with. But you seem to use `NextSun` a lot more than you'd want.

Answer (score 0):

So I assume you Always start with Sunday in `B26` and Monday in `B27` and so on, and want to just print the dates for the **next** week – hence the variable name – in column `C`?

Weekday() will only return a number, not a date, so that alone will not likely do what you want. However, you can add it onto the existing date.

```
Sub AutoDate()

    Dim NextDay As Range
    Dim i As Long

    Set NextDay = Range("C26")
    For i = 0 To 6
        NextDay.Offset(i) = Date + (8 - Weekday(Date) + i)
    Next i

End Sub
```

Change that **8** to a **1** if you want the current week.

Answer (score 0):

This will fill seven rows of column B and C with dates of the current week:

```vb
Sub AutoDate()

    Dim NameRange   As Range
    Dim DateRange   As Range
    
    Dim WeekdayDate As Date
    Dim WeekdayName As String
    Dim StartDate   As Date
    Dim Offset      As Long

    Set NameRange = Range("C26")
    Set DateRange = Range("B26")
    
    StartDate = DateAdd("d", 1 - Weekday(Date, vbSunday), Date)
    For Offset = 0 To 6
        WeekdayDate = DateAdd("d", Offset, StartDate)
        WeekdayName = Format(WeekdayDate, "dddd")
        DateRange.Offset(Offset) = WeekdayDate
        NameRange.Offset(Offset) = WeekdayName
    Next

End Sub
```